# How do I use value_counts to select data with a specific value out of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of states and the number of districts they each have. I am trying to use .value_counts to select all states that have 1 district. This is only my second week of my coding class, so I have no experience with this unfortunately.

I've tried .query and .loc, the professor specifically said to use .value_counts. I don't know how to properly set up the code to get the result I'm after.

```
import geopandas
import geopandas as pd
congressLayer = geopandas.read_file(r"C:\Cyber\data\114th_Congress.shp")
dist_per_state = congressLayer["STATE_ABBR"].value_counts()
dist_per_state.keys()

Out: Index(['CA', 'TX', 'FL', 'NY', 'IL', 'PA', 'OH', 'GA', 'MI', 'NC', 'NJ', 'VA',
       'WA', 'AZ', 'IN', 'TN', 'MA', 'MO', 'MN', 'WI', 'MD', 'AL', 'SC', 'CO',
       'LA', 'KY', 'CT', 'OK', 'OR', 'IA', 'AR', 'NV', 'MS', 'KS', 'UT', 'WV',
       'NE', 'NM', 'ME', 'HI', 'RI', 'NH', 'ID', 'ND', 'AK', 'DC', 'MT', 'VT',
       'DE', 'SD', 'WY', 'PR'],
      dtype='object')

dist_per_state
Out: CA    53
TX    36
FL    27
NY    27
IL    18
PA    18
OH    16
GA    14.......
DE     1
SD     1
WY     1
```

Most ways I have tried to set this up I get an error message saying something like I can't use that function with whatever I've tried to input. I just need a list showing states with 1 district.

Comment: dist_per_state[dist_per_state==1].index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. After getting the counts, you can just use the following line to check whether they are equal to 1 and get the appropriate states:

```
dist_per_state = congressLayer["STATE_ABBR"].value_counts()
target_states = dist_per_state[dist_per_state==1].index.values
print(target_states)
```